# How to get convergence error messages or max gradient in lme4

Tags: r, mixed

How could I get max gradient values after doing random effects models with lme4? By default, it is shown if it is more than 0.002, but I want to make an original function as below, which needs a returned value of max gradient, whether the value is more than 0.002 or not.

1. Doing the original model

```
MM<- lmer(Y ~ 1 + X + (1 |cluster_ID ), data=data)
summary(MM)
```

2. If the above original model have the max gradient more than 0.002, then do the below process.

```
MM_par <- getME(MM, c("theta", "fixef"))
RS_MM <- update(MM, start=MM_par, control=lmerControl(optCtrl = list(maxeval=1e4)))
summary(RS_MM)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
```

Extract the `@optinfo` slot and see what's there:

```
names(fm1@optinfo)
```

Check the `$derivs` element:

```
fm1@optinfo$derivs
```

Here's the gradient:

```
max(abs(fm1@optinfo$derivs$gradient))
```

But we want the *scaled* gradient (thanks @RobertLong for the reminder)

```
dd <- fm1@optinfo$derivs
sc_grad <- with(dd, solve(Hessian, gradient))
max(abs(sc_grad))
```

#### notes

- extracting slots directly via `@` is not 100% guaranteed to be future-proof (although `lme4` is pretty stable)
- increasing the maximum number of evaluations won't actually change the max gradient.  You might consider tightening/decreasing the convergence tolerance instead (see `?lme4::convergence`)

Comment: oops, @RobertLong's answer is correct - mine gives the gradient rather than the *scaled* gradient.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the convergence error with:

```
myModel@optinfo$conv$lme4
```

And you can get the max gradient with:

```
myModel@optinfo$derivs %>% with(. , solve(Hessian, gradient))  %>% abs() %>% max()
```